# MVC PagedList first page with no querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I m using the TroyGoode MVC PagedList https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList
Working great except that i have duplicated content on the first page

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewData.Model.EnumerableAds, page => Url.Action("MyPage", "Home", new { page }))
```

Which gave me the HTML output :

```
<div class="pagination-container">
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a href="/home/mypage?page=1" rel="prev">«</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/mypage?page=1">1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a>2</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/mypage?page=3">3</a></li>
<li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="/home/mypage?page=3" rel="next">»</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to remplace :

```
<li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a href="/home/mypage?page=1" rel="prev">«</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/mypage?page=1">1</a></li>
```

by

```
<li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a href="/home/mypage" rel="prev">«</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/mypage">1</a></li>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: There is an example in the link you provided that shows how to accomplish this. Just make the page param nullable and default it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Br4d suggested, here is the code that would accomplish this

```
public ActionResult MyPage(int? page=1)
{
     your code here
}
```

Now you can send a null for the first page and it will default to page 1.

Comment: That is not the problem,    
<div class="pagination-container">
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a href="/home/mypage?page1" rel="prev">«</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/mypage?page=1">1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a>2</a></li>
<li><a href="/home/mypage?page=3">3</a></li>
<li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="/home/mypage?page=3" rel="next">»</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
I want to remplace :
<li><a href="/home/mypage?page=1">1</a></li>
by
<li><a href="/home/mypage">1</a></li>

Comment: If you use the code i have provided, you will be able to do it. have you tried ?

Comment: No error but still have : <div class="pagination-container"> <ul class="pagination"> <li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a href="/home/mypage?page1" rel="prev">«</a></li> <li><a href="/home/mypage?page=1">1</a></li> <li class="active"><a>2</a></li> <li><a href="/home/mypage?page=3">3</a></li> <li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="/home/mypage?page=3" rel="next">»</a></li> </ul> </div> I want to remplace : <li><a href="/home/mypage?page=1">1</a></li> by <li><a href="/home/mypage">1</a></li>

Comment: i wish to /home/mypage instead of /home/mypage?page1 in the view

Comment: use the example above to achieve that @Yanga